# Column has data presented as "x, y" - how do I plot from that into a scatterplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The data has a column that has the x coordinate and y coordinate saved as "x, y" which is stopping me from creating a scatterplot.

Is is possible to plot from that data?

Ex:

```
location
77, 67
108, 31
108, 35
3, 42
7, 43 
2, 76
```

Comment: look at `tidyr::separate`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `separate` from the **tidyr** package to split a column of strings. By default, `separate` will separate on any non-alphanumeric characters. If the `convert` argument to `separate` is set to `TRUE`, then `separate` will convert the split strings into numeric values if possible. See the following example:

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
    location = c('77, 67', '108, 31', '108, 35', '3, 42', '7, 43', '2, 76'),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

separate(df, location, c('x', 'y'), convert = TRUE)
#     x  y
# 1  77 67
# 2 108 31
# 3 108 35
# 4   3 42
# 5   7 43
# 6   2 76
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
dt <- data.table(location=list(c(77,67),c(108,31),c(108,35)))
dt[,x:=location[[1]][1],by=1:nrow(dt)]
dt[,y:=location[[1]][2],by=1:nrow(dt)]
```